# insert into table1 from table2, but table1 have primary key VB.NET SQL.server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, for-loop, insert, primary-key

table1

id(PK)  |name   |age

---

table2

name    |age

aaa     |25

bbb     |25

ccc     |20

---

the result:

id(PK)  |name   |age

1   |aaa    |25

2   |bbb    |25

3   |ccc    |20

---

how to insert into table1 from select table2 where column(id) in tabel1 is (PK)

i used this

```
 Load_check_pieces2_true(Max_check_id2)
    For x As Integer = 1 To dt_chex_pieces2_true.Rows.Count
        Max_Orderid = Max_order_id() + x
        insert_Orders(Max_Orderid, Max_shift_id, dt_chex_pieces2_true.Rows(x)("check_id").ToString)
    Next
```

Comment: Ok but where is your problem?

Comment: how to insert into table1 from select table2 where column(id) in tabel1 is (PK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while inserting into the table1 use the following option just above the insert script:
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ON;

INSERT INTO () values ();

this will solve your issue.